# Is there a way of recording keystrokes while editing?

Tags: feature-request, editor

When inserting a block of code, several lines, previously copied with CTRL/C, and pasted with CTRL/V, I have do "down" "home" four "space"s, over and over. Please, is there a way to record these keystrokes and re-play them with a single key?

Of course marking up a many lined block of code may be already allowed for, but I could not locate it in the Help. Even so, it would be a useful feature, and is found in emacs and probably other text editors.

Comment: for multi-line code, highlight all the code and then hit **ctrl k**

Comment: I apologise for the duplicate, I missed that other question when I posted mine. So this can be deleted if there is a mechanism to do so.